# La expresión «a juzgar por» ¿va separada por una coma?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, locuciones, redacción

No sé si tiene que ir precedida o seguida de comas la oración que inicie la expresión «a juzgar por».

Por ejemplo:
«A juzgar por este primer resultado(,) es bastante prometedor lo que nos espera como trabajadores».
«Parece una buena persona(,) a juzgar por su apariencia».

¿Esas comas que están entre paréntesis son ortográficamente correctas?

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, en efecto. una coma es necesaria para separar la expresión `a juzgar por`, tanto sea ésta usada al inicio como al final de la oración

> ***A juzgar por este primer resultado,** es bastante prometedor lo que nos espera como trabajadores*

o

> Parece una buena persona, **a juzgar por su apariencia**

La necesidad de su empleo (según entiendo) está justificada por la Real Academia Española cuando consigna [las reglas del uso normativo de la coma](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma).

Encuentro, por ejemplo, que para el caso de la expresión al inicio, allí se dice:

> *1.2.12. Se escribe coma detrás de los complementos encabezados por locuciones preposicionales de valor introductorio, del tipo en cuanto a, respecto de, con respecto a, en relación con, con referencia a, a tenor de, etc.: En cuanto a ti, no quiero volver a verte; A tenor de lo visto, no creo que cambie mucho la situación. De la misma manera, se pone coma detrás de los elementos encabezados por locuciones preposicionales o adverbiales de valor condicional, concesivo, final, causal, etc.: En ese caso, nos quedaremos en casa; A pesar de todo, conseguimos nuestro objetivo; Para eso, hubiera sido mejor que no hablaras; Aun así, nadie te lo va a agradecer.*

Para el segundo caso, con la locución al final, la coma es igualmente necesaria, (tal como se especifica en el inciso **(b)**):

> *1.2.8. Se escribe coma delante de las conjunciones o locuciones conjuntivas que unen las oraciones incluidas en una oración compuesta, en los casos siguientes:*
>
> (...)
>
> ***b)** Ante oraciones consecutivas introducidas por conque, así que, de manera que, etc.: Prometiste acompañarla, así que ahora no te hagas el remolón.*